# HTTP Response splitting in case of java

Tags: java, httpresponse, response-headers

Is HTTP Response splitting possible in below case:

```
String requestFilename = request.getParameter("name");

response.addHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=" + requestFilename);
```

I am directly appending the unsanitized request parameter to the reponse header.

My Question is that by using CRLF characters can we insert our own header into response.

So far i have tried `\r\n` and `%0D%0A` but they do not work.

Is `response.addHeader()` immune to such attacks?
Can someone explain it to me how this attack can be executed?

Comment: I would assume that addHeader is escaping whatever you pass it.

Comment: Looking for some definite answers. Please help

Answer (score 1):

Whether http response splitting is possible in your case will depend on the servlet container that is hosting the code.

For example, Tomcat guards against common security vunerabilities, with the [CORS Filter](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-9.0-doc/config/filter.html#CORS_Filter) dealing with response splitting (at least for the incoming request).

Tomcat also filters the values written to the response - see [Http11OutputBuffer (line 383)](https://github.com/apache/tomcat/blob/master/java/org/apache/coyote/http11/Http11OutputBuffer.java#L383), which prevents corrupt values being returned to the client should they somehow end up as a header value.

Never say never, but if you're using an upto date version of popular web-server like Tomcat, you should be safe from well known vunerabilities like response splitting.